# Story where anything that was wished wouldn't happen, happened

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have been trying to remember this story I read when I was young for years with no success, perhaps you could help.

I believe it was a short story, but perhaps a small novel like of the Goosebumps series. It was of a low reading level because I was in early gradeschool when reading it (roughly 11+ years ago).

The main premise (that I remember) was that a small child was (trapped?) in a house, scary things kept happening to the child as they tried navigating the house. In one particular scene the child was in a dark room and reached out to find the lightswitch, while thinking "I hope nothing meets my hand at the light switch" and sure enough another hand met hers at the switch. It was later revealed that any bad thoughts such as "I hope *blank* doesn't happen" would come true, so the child had to twist that and conquer their fear/use happy thoughts to escape.